# SQLAlchemy with_for_update reads stale data

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm writing a function that's responsible for updating account balance. In order to prevent concurrent updates, I'm first using `with_for_update()` to grab a lock on the accounts, calculate the amount, update the balances, and then commit the session. In order to simulate concurrent requests, I spawn off two processes and run the function once in each. Here's the code for calculating the and updating the balances:

```
session = create_db_session(db_engine)()
session.connection(execution_options={'isolation_level': 'SERIALIZABLE'})

print("&" * 80)
print(f"{process_number} entering!")
print("&" * 80)

accounts = (
    session.query(Account)
    .filter(Account.id == [some account IDs])
    .with_for_update()
    .populate_existing()
    .all()
)

print("*" * 80)
print(f"{process_number} got here!")
for account in accounts:
    print(
        f"Account version: {account.version}. Name: {account.name}. Balance: {account.balance}"
    )
    print(hex(id(session)))
    print("*" * 80)

# Calculate the total amount outstanding by account.
for account in accounts:
    total_amount = _calculate_total_amount()
    if account.balance >= total_amount:
        # For accounts with sufficient balance, deduct the amount from the balance.
        account.balance -= total_amount
    else:
        # Otherwise, save them for notification. Code omitted.

print("-" * 80)
print(f"{process_number} committing!")
for li, account in line_items_accounts:
    print(
        f"Account version: {account.version}. Name: {account.name}. Balance: {account.balance}"
    )
    print("-" * 80)
session.commit()
```

Here's the output:

```
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
0 entering!
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
1 entering!
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
********************************************************************************
0 got here!
Account version: 1. Name: Phi's Account. Balance: 20000.000000
0x7fcb65d7e0d0
********************************************************************************
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0 committing!
Account version: 1. Name: Phi's Account. Balance: 19930.010000
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
********************************************************************************
1 got here!
Account version: 1. Name: Phi's Account. Balance: 20000.000000
0x7fcb65f930a0
********************************************************************************
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 committing!
Account version: 1. Name: Phi's Account. Balance: 19930.010000
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

0 and 1 are process numbers, and the hexadecimal number is the id of the session. You can see that the lock worked (process 0 blocked 1 until 0 committed), but 1 read stale data: the balance should have been `19930.01`, not `20000`, and in the output for process 1, the "Account version" should have been 2, not 1.

I've tried using `populate_existing()` with no luck, although I suspect it was not going to be helpful anyway since the two sessions are distinct, and the session for process 1 shouldn't have populated anything until the lock is released by process 0. I've also tried "repeatable read" and "serializable" isolation levels, and was expecting an exception to be thrown in process 1 due to concurrent updates/read/write dependency between transactions, but nothing happend.

It's also interesting to note that the behavior is not consistent. Things work correctly when I run the block of code above locally, but almost never work when I build a Docker container with all the code and run it there. There is no difference in the package versions. I'm using Postgres and psycopg2.

I'm banging my head against the wall now trying to figure out what is happening. I feel like maybe I overlooked something simple. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible that this is occurring because you aren't comitting or flushing the session?

Comment: @YaakovBressler I have session.commit() at the end of the block so I doubt that's the case?

Comment: It appears you're getting this issue because your processes are sharing the same thread and same session pool. I'm not completely sure though... Outside of my expertise...

Comment: I don't think they are sharing the same thread? They are two processes. If two processes are sharing the same thread then something is seriously wrong about Python.

Comment: Also can you clarify what you meant by "session pool"? Like connection pool?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. [This code](https://pastebin.com/kFS9DRkH) works fine for me with `mysql+mysqlconnector`.

Comment: @GordThompson Updated the question to note that I'm using Postgres and psycopg2. I've also noted in the original question that the behavior is inconsistent - I can't reproduce this locally, but it almost always happens when I run it in a Docker container.

Comment: Is a PostgreSQL instance running inside the Docker container as well? If so, can you have the Python code in the Docker container hit the same PostgreSQL server as the code you run locally?

Comment: @GordThompson great question - no, the postgres instance is running in its own container, which is more similar to the actual production setup where we have an RDS instance running remotely.

Comment: IMO, one thing you need to try and ascertain is whether the difference in behaviour is caused by something on the (database) server side or something on the client side. That's why I suggested trying to hit the *same* database server from both client locations.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter `with_for_update` is automatically kept in the session. In this case `session.commit` is writing it back to the database!

Comment: @rfkortekaas: Thanks for clearing this up. One possible explanation then: the (redundant!) protection with the `SERIALIZABLE` snapshot isolation strikes and raises a serialization failure *after* the output has been printed to prematurely suggest "mission accomplished", while the mission has, in fact, not been accomplished, yet - i.e. written to the DB. 
ljiatu, did you check for error messages in the DB log? Possible solution: use default `READ COMMITTED` transaction isolation. Cheaper, too.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter that's not really the problem. I tried all three different transaction isolation levels.

Answer (score 3):

`FOR UPDATE` would do the trick. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-ROWS)

> `FOR UPDATE` causes the rows retrieved by the `SELECT` statement to be
> locked as though for update. This prevents them from being locked,
> modified or deleted by other transactions until the current
> transaction ends. That is, other transactions that attempt `UPDATE`,
> `DELETE`, **`SELECT FOR UPDATE`**, `SELECT FOR NO KEY UPDATE`, `SELECT FOR SHARE` or `SELECT FOR KEY SHARE` of these rows will be blocked
> until the current transaction ends;

Bold emphasis mine.

And that's exactly what SQLAlchemy's `with_for_update()` does. [The manual:](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/current/notfound.html)

> When called with no arguments, the resulting `SELECT` statement will have a `FOR UPDATE` clause appended.

**However**, this is redundant effort while operating with `SERIALIZABLE` snapshot isolation like you do. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE)

> This level emulates serial transaction execution for all committed transactions; as if transactions had been executed one after another, serially, rather than concurrently.

So your code is safe against race conditions, redundantly. **Either** use `FOR UPDATE` (recommended!), **or** use `SERIALIZABLE` transactions. The latter is typically substantially more expensive. And you need to prepare for serialization failures (not in your displayed code). [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE)

> ... like the Repeatable Read level, applications using this level
> must be prepared to retry transactions due to serialization failures.

The elephant in the room: **Did you actually write to the DB?** `session.commit()` may have failed *after* "mission accomplished" has been printed prematurely.

Check the DB log for serialization failures or any other exception. If you (unsurprisingly) find serialization failures, the simple **solution** is to switch to (default!) `READ COMMITED` isolation level. Your manual locking already does the job.

Comment: Added a comment in the original question - I tried all three transaction isolation levels, but none works.

Comment: Also, would it really be worth the effort to do manual locking instead of using stricter isolation levels? With manual locking, one thing I would have to worry about is deadlock prevention, which could be quite difficult with a large app. I was contemplating just using SERIALIZABLE everywhere and retry on failure, and not having to worry about grabbing locks.

Comment: @ljiatu: Well, you already *have* manual locking with `FOR UPDATE` in place. And yes, that's typically substantially cheaper than `SERIALIZABLE` transactons. That aside, if you already tried all isolation levels, then there is another problem in your setup, which I am not able to identify. (But did you check the db logs for error msg?)